# Groovy: map reduce list of maps

Tags: groovy, mapreduce, functional-programming

Assuming I have list of maps in Groovy:

```
def listOfMaps = [
[k: 1, n: 'Name1', d1: 'a', d2: 'b'],
[k: 2, n: 'Name2', d1: 'c', d2: 'd'],
[k: 1, n: 'Name3', d1: 'e', d2: 'f'],
[k: 4, n: 'Name4', d1: 'g', d2: 'h']]
```

I need to find if there exist (or not) items, where `k` is equal, but `n` is not. E.g. in this case we have two map records with "k" = 1 and "n" is 'Name1' and 'Name3'. How can I find such data?
I suppose I should group by "k" and count distinct values in "n", if there are more than 1 unique values in "n" for certain "k" - we found such data.
I'm completely stuck so any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

Now I've worked out what you meant, here's the code:

```
listOfMaps.groupBy { 
   it.k }.
values().
findAll { l -> 
   l.size() > 1 && (l.size() == l.unique { e -> e.n }.size()) 
}
```

At the beginning the list is grouped by `k` element, then among the values we search for lists with size higher than 1 and which size is equal to count of unique `n` elements. It works correctly.

**OLD ANSWERS**

You can try the combination of `findAll` and `unique`:

```
def listOfMaps = [
    [k: 1, n: 'Name1', d1: 'a', d2: 'b'],
    [k: 2, n: 'Name2', d1: 'c', d2: 'd'],
    [k: 1, n: 'Name3', d1: 'e', d2: 'f'],
    [k: 4, n: 'Name4', d1: 'g', d2: 'h'],
]

listOfMaps.findAll { it.k == 1 }.unique { it.n }
```

Or with `groupBy`:

```
listOfMaps.groupBy { it.k }[1].unique { it.n }
```

In groovy there are many ways of doing it ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
listOfMaps.groupBy { [it.k, it.n] }.keySet().countBy { it[0] }.any { it.value > 1 }
```

All you need is a combination of `k`'s and `n`'s to compare. You can `groupBy` the way you want it. I preferred to group by a list so that I can `getAt(0)` to check if duplicates exist. Since, `keySet()` is a `Set`, no two items ( which are lists ) will be the same. Then we just have to check that the first item (k) is unique or not.

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in a reducing version, this one builds a map of `k` to a set of `n`s.

```
def r = listOfMaps.inject([:].withDefault{[].toSet()}) { m, it -> 
    m.get(it.k).add(it.n); m }
println r.findAll{ it.value.size()>1 }
// => [1:[Name3, Name1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out a way to compare *n*, but give this a shot:

```
// Finds a match
assert [[k: 1, n: 'Name1', d1: 'a', d2: 'b'],
[k: 2, n: 'Name2', d1: 'c', d2: 'd'],
[k: 1, n: 'Name3', d1: 'e', d2: 'f'],
[k: 4, n: 'Name4', d1: 'g', d2: 'h']]
    .groupBy { it.k }    
    .collectEntries {k, v ->
        ["$k": v.unique()]
    }    
    .findAll { it.value.size() > 1 } != [:]

// Does not find a match
assert [[k: 2, n: 'Name2', d1: 'c', d2: 'd'],
[k: 1, n: 'Name3', d1: 'e', d2: 'f'],
[k: 4, n: 'Name4', d1: 'g', d2: 'h']]
    .groupBy { it.k }    
    .collectEntries {k, v ->
        ["$k": v.unique()]
    }    
    .findAll { it.value.size() > 1 } == [:]
```

### EDIT

I take that back. n can be compared with unique():

```
[[k: 1, n: 'Name1', d1: 'a', d2: 'b'],
[k: 2, n: 'Name2', d1: 'c', d2: 'd'],
[k: 1, n: 'Name3', d1: 'e', d2: 'f'],
[k: 4, n: 'Name4', d1: 'g', d2: 'h']]
    .groupBy { it.k }    
    .collectEntries {k, v ->
        ["$k": v.unique { a, b -> (a.k == b.k && a.n == b.n) ? 0 : 1 }]
    }    
    .findAll { it.value.size() > 1 } != [:]
```

It's amazing what can come out while sitting on the toilet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Groovy is very groovy indeed, and you can use different methods to achieve same goal.

I'll add `groupBy` + `unique` + `grep` approach. It may be easier to understand.

Basically what you need is do a group by collect / unique to reduce dimension, and then grep by size of collection you get.

```
def find = { 
    it.groupBy { it.k } // Fold one dimension
        .grep { it.value.size() > 1 } // filter results by that
        .grep { it.value*.n.unique().size() > 1 } // fold and repeat
        .collectEntries() // back to map
}

def listOfMaps = [
    [k: 1, n: 'Name1', d1: 'a', d2: 'b'],
    [k: 2, n: 'Name2', d1: 'c', d2: 'd'],
    [k: 1, n: 'Name3', d1: 'e', d2: 'f'],
    [k: 4, n: 'Name4', d1: 'g', d2: 'h']]


assert find(listOfMaps) == [1: [[k: 1, n: 'Name1', d1: 'a', d2: 'b'], [k: 1, n: 'Name3', d1: 'e', d2: 'f']]]

listOfMaps[2].n = "Name1" // Make them equals.
assert find(listOfMaps) == [:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Late, but here`s one more:

```
listOfMaps.groupBy( [{ it.k }, { it.n }] )
        .findAll { _, v -> v.size() > 1}
        .collect { _, v -> v.values().collectMany{ it } }
```

Compared to @Opal's answer, this allows the list to contain duplicates:

```
def listOfMaps = [
        [k: 2, n: 'Name2', d1: 'c', d2: 'd'],
        [k: 2, n: 'Name2', d1: 'c', d2: 'd'],
        [k: 2, n: 'Name3', d1: 'c', d2: 'd']
]
```